# How to find point of a function maximum

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, roots

Given parameters:

- L - the lowest point,
- R - the point where chart crosses zero,
- b - some coefficient;

a function $f$ is defined as follows:

$$f(x) = ( \frac {L} {R^6}  x^6 - L) e ^ {-bx^2}$$

A chart for this function ($L=0.5$, $R=1$, $b=1$), looks like this:
[image: Chart for f(x)]

How to find the $x$ of a maximum point, where derivative of $f$ crosses zero?

I can see that solution is at $x~=1.7$, but I failed to solve it analytically...

Do you know, how to solve it?
Or is analytical solution possible at all?

Comment: How is a pivot point defined?

Comment: Of course, I was wrong. I mixed up point of maximum with pivot point. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the derivative of $f(x)$ and set it to zero,

$$f'(x) = e ^ {-bx^2} \frac {L} {R^2} \left[-2b(x^6-R^2)x+6x^5\right] =0$$

or, with $R=1$ and $b=1$,

$$x\left(x^6-3x^4-1\right)=0$$

which has the obvious solution at $x=0$ for the minimum value. Note that the cubic equation in $x^2$ has only one real root and it is given analytically by

$$x^2= 1+\left(\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{1/3} +\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{1/3}$$

Thus, the maximum values are at $x =\pm 1.762$.

Comment: Now I see: you have just ignored the term: e^(-b*x^2) as it does not help to find root when x > 0. Nice! Thank you